# UITableViewCell Image gets Larger when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on an app that includes some functionality that shows a list of photo albums. I'm using a vanilla `UITableView` and vanilla `UITableViewCell`s. I'm using a `Subtitle` Style `UITableViewCell` and setting a thumbnail image on `cell.imageView.image`. Note: This is not a custom cell, it's the built-in cell imageView.

The problem is that when I tap a cell, the imageView gets LARGER, which then looks weird, because a) that's not intuitive behavior and b) it no longer matches up with every other row.

Before the selection, the cell's imageView frame is:

```
cell.imageView.frame: {{16, 1}, {84, 84}}
```

After the selection, the cells' imageView frame is:

```
cell.imageView.frame: {{16, 0}, {88, 87.5}}
```

I don't have any code involved, this is a vanilla UITableViewCell.

[image]

The only code I have that interacts with the imageView is the PhotoKit code which I use to fetch the photo asset and update the cell:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;

[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                 targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                    options:options
              resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

                  // Only update the thumbnail if the cell tag hasn't changed.
                  // Otherwise, the cell has been re-used.
                  if (cell.tag == currentTag) {
                      cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                      cell.imageView.image = result;
                  }

              }];
```

Why is this happening? How can I stop it?

Comment: I think your tableView's `heightForRowAtIndex:` method is returning smaller value than cell's height that should be. To test if it's working, return some significant large value from this method.

Answer (score 0):

your custom UITableViewCell have a outlet with name "imageView" which cause the problem. remove that outlet and the problem is fixed

Answer (score -2):

i find when you set the UIImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

if you request a web image ,and download has finish and callback,the imageview will be change it's frame

you can try this method

```
[img setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: The image isn't showing more and therefore doesn't need to be slipped. It's taking the same image data, pulled from the PhotoKit not from the web, and just showing it in a larger frame. Clipping won't help because the frame has physically gotten larger.